# Translating PHP over to Java (Strange {})

Tags: java, php

So I'm trying to translate this code over to Java. $len is an int, $offset is an int, and $buffer is a String. What do the {} mean as part of "{$this->offset}" and how would I translate those over to Java code?

```
for(; $len > 0; --$len, ++$this->offset){
            $buffer .= @$this->buffer{$this->offset};
}
```

Comment: It's for variable encapsulation. That's simply an integer. `buffer1`, `buffer2`, so forth.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy wow, that's highly special. Who needs arrays when you can just make up slots with numbers in their names!

Comment: @Amadan you'd probably want to do `getattr(self, 'buffer' + offset)` for python.

Comment: @Amadan 'buffer' isn't a prefix though. Wouldn't it be 'map.get(this.buffer + offset)'?

Comment: It may not work for your needs, and it may well be *cheating*. But, [quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) is a GPL PHP5 interpreter in Java.

Comment: @JoshuaGarde: Yes, totally right. I misread it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch My purpose isn't to just get the PHP code running in a Java virtual machine, it's to convert the entire PHP code into native Java code.